# Identifying source of unwanted vertical displacement of div in certain circumstances

Tags: html, css

I'm building a "system health" screen in a web UI for an appliance. Part of that is a bank of gauges to display power supply voltages. The gauges are constructed from a stack of 'inline-block' divs. They're constructed client-side based on a JSON description (threshold levels, reading, title etc.), but I don't believe that is in any way contributing to my problem as I can reproduce it with static HTML. By changing the 'top' property of the .needle element, the reading can be updated live. The gauge is split into 7 segments : good and hi/lo warn, critical, fatal. As long as they're symmetrical, everything looks fine. If I rearrange things so that my gauge is zero based, the low fatal band correctly expands to extend all the way to zero. The unwanted side effect is that the whole gauge offsets down the page by the height difference between lo-fatal and hi-fatal.

The code below is a self-contained demonstration of the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <!-- IMPORTANT - After any changes, check this against the w3c validator:
         http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload
         Anything other than a clean pass is not acceptable!
    //-->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
        <title>WTF?!?</title>
        <style type="text/css">


            .gaugeset {
                background          : #f8f8f8;
                font-family         : sans-serif;
                font-size           : 70%;

                border              : thin solid #ccc;
                display             : inline-block;
                text-align          : center;
            }

            .gauge {
                background          : #f0f0f0;
                font-family         : sans-serif;

                border              : thin solid #ccc;

                margin              : 7px;
                display             : inline-block;
                border              : thin solid black;
            }

            .gauge > h1 {
                background          : white;
                font-size           : 120%;
                text-align          : center;

                -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
                -moz-border-radius  : 5px 5px 0px 0px;
                border-radius       : 5px 5px 0px 0px;

                margin              : 0px;
                padding-left        : 7px;
                padding-right       : 7px;
            }

            .readout {
                display             : inline-block;
                height              : 180px;
                width               : 24px;
                margin              : 7px;
                margin-left         : 27px;
                margin-right        : 45px;
                border              : thin solid #ccc;
            }

            .fatal {
                background              : #ff7f7f;
                height                  : 10%;
            }

            .critical {
                height                  : 10%;
                background              : #ffbf7f;
            }

            .warn {
                height                  : 10%;
                background              : #ffff7f;
            }

            .good {
                height                  : 40%;
                background              : #c0ffc0;
            }

            #asymetric .fatal {
                height                  : 18px;
            }

            #asymetric .critical {
                height                  : 22px;
            }

            #asymetric .warn {
                height                  : 6px;
            }

            #asymetric .good {
                height                  : 19px;
            }

            #asymetric #special {
                height                  : 87px;
            }

            .needle {
                position                : relative;
                left                    : 27px;
                top                     : 45px;
                line-height             : 0;                    /* So that the tip of the arrow is where we want it */
            }

            /* The text to the left that marks the transitions between zones */
            .marker {
                position                : relative;
                right                   : 29px;
                text-align              : right;
                line-height             : 0;
                font-size               : 70%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="gaugeset">
            <div class="gauge">
                <h1>1.0V</h1>
                <div class="readout" id="asymetric">
                    <div class="needle">&#9664&nbsp;-.--V</div>
                    <div class="fatal"></div><div class="marker">1.4v</div>
                    <div class="critical"></div><div class="marker">1.3v</div>
                    <div class="warn"></div><div class="marker">1.2v</div>
                    <div class="good"></div><div class="marker">0.8v</div>
                    <div class="warn"></div><div class="marker">0.7v</div>
                    <div class="critical"></div><div class="marker">0.6v</div>
                    <div class="fatal" id="special"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gauge">
                <h1>1.0V</h1>
                <div class="readout">
                    <div class="needle">&#9664&nbsp;-.--V</div>
                    <div class="fatal"></div><div class="marker">1.4v</div>
                    <div class="critical"></div><div class="marker">1.3v</div>
                    <div class="warn"></div><div class="marker">1.2v</div>
                    <div class="good"></div><div class="marker">0.8v</div>
                    <div class="warn"></div><div class="marker">0.7v</div>
                    <div class="critical"></div><div class="marker">0.6v</div>
                    <div class="fatal"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've been all over it with Firebug inspecting the elements visually and checking the computed heights, tops etc. without success. Something in the assymetric gauge is 'snagging' and disrupting the intended document flow. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top` to `.gauge`, because it has `display: inline-block`.

Read this, particularly the section talking about "baseline" to understand why `vertical-align` matters: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

In general, whenever you use `inline-block`, you should consider setting `vertical-align` (unless you're happy with the default of `baseline`).

You can see a comparison of the common values of `vertical-align` combined with `inline-block` here: http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html

Comment: That does indeed fix it, but it feels like it shouldn't need fixing in the first place. Both gauge divs are the exact same dimensions, so I don't understand which elements baselines are causing the mis-alignment.